# Best method to present a fullscreen radial gradient in web to prevent banding

Tags: website-design, svg, gradient, css, noise

Is it better to generate a fullscreen radial gradient in CSS3 or with a maximized SVG vector? How would you implement the maximized SVG?
Do you think that it's necessary to apply a raster noise background-repeat?

Comment: What type of gradient? Do you have an example? What do you mean when you say "raster noise"?

Comment: I would use CSS3 to create this gradient but I'm not quite sure of what you want to do. Can you show us an image?